# Pipe chaining in my own shell implementation

Tags: c, bash, shell

I am currently writing my own shell implementation in C. I understood the principle behind piping and redirecting the fds. However, some specific behavior with pipes has attracted my attention:

- cat | ls (or any command that does not read from stdin as final element of the pipe).

In that case, what happens in the shell is that ls executes and cat asks for a single line before exiting (resulting from a SIGPIPE I guess). I have tried to follow this tutorial to better understand the principle behind multiple pipes: http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~mamrak.1/CIS762/pipes_lab_notes.html

Below is some code I have written to try to replicate the behavior I am looking for:

```
char    *cmd1[] = {"/bin/cat", NULL};
char    *cmd2[] = {"/bin/ls", NULL};
int     pdes[2];
pid_t   child;

if (!(child = fork()))
{
    pipe(pdes);
    if (!fork())
    {
        close(pdes[0]);
        dup2(pdes[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        /* cat command gets executed here */
        execvp(cmd1[0], cmd1);
    }
    else
    {
        close(pdes[1]);
        dup2(pdes[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        /* ls command gets executed here */
        execvp(cmd2[0], cmd2);
    }
}
wait(NULL);
```

I am aware of the security flaws of that implementation but this is just for testing. The problem with that code as I understand it is that whenever ls gets executed, it just exits and then cat runs in the background somehow (and in my case fail because it tries to read during the prompt of zsh as my program exits). I cannot find a solution to make it work like it should be. Because if I wait for the commands one by one, such commands as **cat /dev/random | head -c 10** would run forever...

If anyone has a solution for this issue or at least some guidance it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not interested in the command usefulness whatsoever. I am only interested in replicating bash behavior which is: display the output of ls first, and running cat that will take only one line then (i.e. prompt the user for one line)

Comment: In your example, `cat` becomes a grandchild while `ls` is a child. `wait` only waits for `ls`. You should instead make both `cat` and `ls` direct children, and then wait for both.

Comment: @thatotherguy Yes indeed I just experimented your solution and it definitely works. And it seems like this solution is close to the first idea offered in the tutorial I linked. However, what happens if I want to extend this for multiple commands? That's the reason why the second implementation looks more interesting to me! I should be able to have many chained commands. With that solution, it seems like I'll have to know in advance how many commands I have to prepare the pipes and the forks no?

Comment: The second idea (and your original post) necessarily only waits for the last command in the pipeline. This is explicitly valid behavior in [POSIX shells](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_02), but it's not what Zsh and Bash do it. If you need the Zsh behavior, you have to do it the first way. You can do both with an unknown number of elements (it's similar to iterative vs recursive traversals of linked lists).

Comment: @thatotherguy Ok I think I get it, I'll try to implement that tomorrow and eventually come back with a solution on that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consideration of comments from @thatotherguy here is the solution I found as implemented in my code. Please bear in mind that **pipe** and **fork** calls should be checked for errors but this version is meant to be as simple as possible. Extra **exit** calls are also necessary for some of my built-in commands.

```
void    exec_pipe(t_ast *tree, t_sh *sh)
{
    int     pdes[2];
    int     status;
    pid_t   child_right;
    pid_t   child_left;

    pipe(pdes);
    if (!(child_left = fork()))
    {
        close(pdes[READ_END]);
        dup2(pdes[WRITE_END], STDOUT_FILENO);
        /* Execute command to the left of the tree */
        exit(execute_cmd(tree->left, sh));
    }
    if (!(child_right = fork()))
    {
        close(pdes[WRITE_END]);
        dup2(pdes[READ_END], STDIN_FILENO);
        /* Recursive call or execution of last command */
        if (tree->right->type == PIPE_NODE)
            exec_pipe(tree->right, sh);
        else
            exit(execute_cmd(tree->right, sh));
    }
    /* Should not forget to close both ends of the pipe */
    close(pdes[WRITE_END]);
    close(pdes[READ_END]);
    wait(NULL);
    waitpid(child_right, &status, 0);
    exit(get_status(status));
}
```

I was confused with the original link I posted and the different ways to handle chained pipes. From the link to the POSIX documented posted below my original question (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_02) it appears that:

> If the pipeline is not in the background (see Asynchronous Lists), the shell shall wait for the last command specified in the pipeline to complete, and may also wait for all commands to complete.

Both behavior are therefore accepted: waiting for last command, or waiting for all of them. I chose to implement the second behavior to stick to what bash/zsh would do.